# Como redirecionar uma página de resultado de busca (/busca?termo=brasil) para outra página (/pais/brasil)

Tags: php, formulário, get, redirecionamento

Estou montando um site de receitas que tem uma busca que é um formulário com método GET e consulta MYSQL para trazer os resultados.

Eu queria que quando alguém fizer uma busca específica, por exemplo brasil, ele fosse para uma página específica que já foi criada, ex: /busca?termo=brasil, será redirecionada para /pais/brasil.

Qual a melhor forma de se fazer isso?

Comment: tem as receitas, ele usa pega o termo e procura na lista de ingredientes (campo ingredientes), a consulta é: SELECT * FROM receitas WHERE ingredientes LIKE '%termo_de_busca%'

Comment: se digitar busca?termo=farinha vai pra que página já que farinha deve ter em um monte de receitas

Comment: alias, desculpa, ele busca nos campos ingredientes, nome_receita e paises, pq pode escolher por ingrediente, nome da receita e pais. Ele ca na pagina que faz essa consulta, traz todas as receitas que usam farinha, mas daí quero fazer uma pag customizada só para farinha, por exemplo

Comment: é que eu queria facilitar para a pessoa, sem ela precisar clicar

Comment: farinha vai para o resultado que traz todas as receitas que usam farinha

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução: https://www.formget.com/how-to-redirect-a-url-php-form/

Ao fazer a pesquisa ele verifica o termo que foi buscado, aí se for igual ao que predefini, ele direciona:

Busca:

```
echo'
<form method="get" action="/busca">
<input type="text" name="termo" placeholder="Procure por receita ou ingrediente...">
<button name="submit" type="submit" >Procurar</button>
</form>';
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/busca-receitas/direciona.php');
```

Faz uma "pré-consulta" antes de trazer o resultado

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
$name = $_GET['termo'];
if($termo =='brasil'){       header("Location:http://componente.pratodoprato.com.br/pais/brasil");
}else{
header("Location:http://componente.pratodoprato.com.br/busca?termo=cebola");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Então o problema se resumia ao termo `brasil`? Na pergunta vc disse `por exemplo brasil` e na sua resposta `brasil`seria a unica opção a se verificar